# NPM packages: command not found

Tags: nodejs, npm

I follow the option 2 of the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions):

```
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
touch .profile
```

add this line `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

```
source ~/.profile
```

But the terminal still returning command not found.

Comment: What command is not found, exactly? those instructions seem to relate to where npm will install its packages - not where the system will look for the npm binary

Comment: @steeldriver I install jshint globally as a test and type jshint. The terminal return command not found